# Reset underscore (`_`) variable in Jupyter notebook powered by IPython kernel

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, ipython

**Edit**: The issue has been reported in [GitHub](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/11325). I'm leaving the question here in case it helps other people find the issue (I was not able to).

---

I often use the `_` variable for convenience when working in a Jupyter notebook (it returns the output of the latest code execution). However, when `_` is used to as a placeholder for an unused variable (a typical use case in Python), it breaks the first use case.

Note that this works as expected in an IPython console. Below, `_` again holds the latest returned value after being used as an unused placeholder in the loop.

```
In [1]: 'value'
Out[1]: 'value'

In [2]: _
Out[2]: 'value'

In [3]: for _ in range(2):
   ...:     print('hello')
   ...:     
hello
hello

In [4]: _
Out[4]: 1

In [5]: 'value'
Out[5]: 'value'

In [6]: _
Out[6]: 'value'
```

However, after running the same code in a Jupyter notebook, `_` will forever hold `1` (the last value from the loop), no matter what the latest output is. If I try to `del _`, then `_` will no longer be an accessible variable.

In short, the two uses of the `_` variable in Python clash in a Jupyter notebook, but **not** in an IPython console. It's only an inconvenience, but I would be curious to know how to solve it - or why it is.

---

**Edit**:

```
$ python --version
Python 3.6.3 :: Anaconda, Inc.
$ ipython --version
6.5.0
$ jupyter notebook --version
5.6.0
```

Comment: Are you running the two pieces of code in different cells in Jupyter?

Comment: Yes. If I copy paste each IPython "cell" above in as many Jupyter notebook cells, then at the end `_` will hold `1` instead of `'value'`.

Comment: Its the same with all "reserved" names in python, if you overide them the original use is gone.
If you assign `print="fo"` you can no longer print stuff.
```>>> print="a"
>>> print(a)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
>>>```
  You could use double underscores as the throwaway var instead. `for __ in range(2):`

Comment: Thanks @BendikKnapstad. What I find strange, however, is that this does not happen in an IPython console...

Comment: See the bug report [here](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/11325)

Comment: @rtoijala I looked for that but could not find it, thanks!

Comment: @BendikKnapstad double and triple underscore are also variables referencing previous code execution. Respectively 2 and 3 executions before

Comment: @LuizFerraz oh, you learn something every day. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way is the following:

```
import builtins
del builtins._
del _
del __
del ___
```

Just ignore any possible errors. In particular, if you get `NameError: name '_' is not defined`, **you must continue deleting `__` etc.**

After doing this, it will continue working **from the subsequent cell** (i.e. this method won't help getting the previous `Out[n]`)

Explanation: in the piece of the code quoted by the other answer ([source](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/blob/d0e254420445c2204a2b39d28948cd6127717fb1/IPython/core/displayhook.py#L211-L220)),

- the code checks if the value of `_`, `__`, `___` (note that `range(1, 4)` excludes `4`! So assigning `____` is useless) is **either undefined or the same object as the last 3 `Out[n]:` values**.
- if it is, then everything is updated.
- otherwise, nothing is updated.

Thus, if all of `_`, `__`, and `___` are undefined, then starting from the next cell, the output will be assigned to `_`.
Importantly, if any one of these are incorrect, **it will not work**.

The `del builtins._` is necessary because otherwise if the user or some library previously did something like

```
import gettext
gettext.NullTranslations().install()
```

then `builtins._` will be overwritten, and it is necessary to delete it.

Answer (score 3):

According to IPython source code
../lib/site-packages/IPython/core/displayhook.py 197 update_user_ns

```
            update_unders = True
            for unders in ['_'*i for i in range(1,4)]:
                if not unders in self.shell.user_ns:
                    continue
                if getattr(self, unders) is not self.shell.user_ns.get(unders):
                    update_unders = False

            self.___ = self.__
            self.__ = self._
            self._ = result
```

To recover underscore variable functionality,just run this code in ipython repl

```
out_len=len(Out)
for index,n in enumerate(Out):
    if index==out_len-1:   _=Out[n]
    if index==out_len-2:  __=Out[n]
    if index==out_len-3: ___=Out[n]
    if index==out_len-4:____=Out[n]
```

Comment: Hm... your code does not work for me. Now `_` is forever `[]`...

Answer (score 3):

One safe way to get the result of the last execution (bypassing the special use of the underscore) is:

```py
from IPython import get_ipython

ipython = get_ipython()

_ = ipython.last_execution_result.result
```

If the last execution did not have a result, then the above will set underscore to `None`.

So, this will not (necessarily) get the result of the last execution *that had a result*.

When the special meaning of underscore is still intact, it will be the result of the last execution that had a result (basically skipping `None` values).

To get that behavior is a little bit more involved.

If your code executes in the global context (so, not in a library), then you can do:

```py
_ = Out.get(max(Out.keys(), default=0))
```

When there is no execution with a result, this will set underscore to `None`.

If your code executes in a library, and you don't want to pass in `globals()`, then you can do:

```py
out_hist = ipython.history_manager.output_hist  # ipython as set above

... out_hist.get(max(out_hist.keys(), default=0)) ...
```