# Any shortcut for the '_' underscore in Python Lab?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter-lab

I would like to check if there is any way that I can add a shortcut for the underscore in Python Lab? I use it a lot for naming the variables, but I think the input is a little annoying for me. I would like to check is there any way I can add a shortcut, like SHIFT + SPACE. Thank you.

Comment: Hi interesting, i wonder if this might be of interest https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56734319/reset-underscore-variable-in-jupyter-notebook-powered-by-ipython-kernel

Comment: @IronMan Thank you for your suggestion. But I think my goal is to find out a shortcut for underscore. A little bit different from that topic.